# How to update the GitHub Repository using terminal?

Tags: github

How to push code in GitHub using terminal `command base`?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: Did iyou already cloned the repo from GitHub ?

Comment: @AhamedSafnaj yes

Comment: Could you pls provide the steps that you have tried ?? It will help to answer your question

Comment: @AhamedSafnaj <br/>Steps<br/>git init <br/> git add . <br/> git commit -m "commit" <br/>git remote add origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git <br/> git push origin master

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Create a new repository on the command line** 
This scenario, if you just created a repo but not cloned it in your pc.

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/novomotus/vitaprice.git
git push -u origin master
```

**If you cloned your repo to your pc**
Here you cloned the repo and made some changes. If you want to push the changes try below method.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push -u origin master
```

For More Information visit this [Link](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/adding-a-file-to-a-repository-using-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the GitHub repository you're interested in, click the green code button, and copy the URL.

[image]

In this example we'll use `https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git`

Then enter the following on the command line:

```
git clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
```

Done.

The other answer is incorrect. e.g. it will create a new repository with a branch called `master`, but your branch on GitHub is most likely to have a branch named `main`. Whilst you can change that by doing `git init -b main` it's semantically wrong. You want to CLONE the repository, not make a NEW ONE which just so happens to track your GitHub repository.